# Highlight that action was done for sure

Tags: past-tense

What is the correct way to highlight that the action was done for sure?

- I **did wrote** that document
- I **did write** that document

The options are similar to how we highlight action in present: we say "I **do** work!" But I'm not sure how to say it in the past.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mplungjan, I know tenses, but it's a quite rare situation. But, yes, maybe it make sense to move it there.

Comment: `I did write that document` is completely correct and emphasizes the fact that you wrote it or you already wrote it depending on where you stress the sentence. Did plus past tense is NEVER correct

Comment: Put your answer as an answer please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`I did write that document` is completely correct and emphasizes the fact that you wrote it or you already wrote it depending on where you stress the sentence.

Did plus past tense is NEVER correct

Comment: +1 If you're just annotating a list, "DONE" works, too.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already pointed out, *I did wrote* (or indeed, *any* past tense verb) is never correct.

But it's also worth mentioning that *I did [infinitive **without** "to"]* is an archaic construction. ***Except*** when it's being used for emphasis. The stress is normally on the word ***did*** - emphasising that you *actually performed the action* (usually, when contradicting someone who's suggested that maybe you ***didn't***), but in some cases the stress may fall on the ("to-less" infinitive) verb...

> *I did **write** to him, but I never actually checked to see if he **received** my letter*.
>    (if *write* is stressed, probably it will be in contrast to another verb which will also be stressed).

If you can't naturally imagine heavy stress on either *did* or the verb following, you don't want *did* at all.

Comment: I'm assuming that the OP would be saying this sentence is response to a question like, "Why did't you write that document?" In which case, the proper response would be, "I *did* write that document."

Comment: @Daniel: Absolutely. In this case OP very specifically says in the question title that he's asking about the emphatic *was done for sure* context. And strictly speaking there's nothing to say apart from the very basic point that when ***did*** is used as an "emphasiser", the "main" verb must be in *infinitive* form (it doesn't have a tense). But many other learners will be unaware that this particular "do-support" usage *only* occurs today in emphatic contexts, whereas a century or two ago it was perfectly normal in *any* context.

Comment: (Note that the question itself has received no upvotes at all, as I write. Because even for learners, it's pretty basic.)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you are highlighting - the fact that you "did" something, or the fact that you "wrote" something.  Use of both verbs is un-necessary, and sounds petulant in both spoken and written English.

The statmement:

```
I *wrote* that document.
```

is both succinct and declarative.

Alternately,

```
I *did* that.
```

is also declarative, but less definitive of what you did - unless there is a context already in play.

Comment: I think the OP is asking, for example, in response to a question like, "Why didn't you write that document?" And the proper response should be, "I *did* write that document."